# javascript to php conversion..chars.substring

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to convert below piece of javascript code to php

```
function randomString(len) {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmn opqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = len;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }

    return randomstring;
}
```

My php code so far ..
EDIT : Working CODE Below

```
     function randomString($len) {
        $chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $string_length = strlen($chars);
        $randomstring = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i< $len; $i++) {
         $rnum = rand(0,$string_length);
         $randomstring.= $chars[$rnum];
        }

        return $randomstring;
    }

echo randomString(16);
```

What does chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1) mean...how can i achieve that in php...i can understand that it takes the particular char of $chars..but what does rnum+1 is for ?

Comment: Maybe you understand the method better when you read [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)? (that's the purpose of documentation, explain how things are used and work).

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for what `substring` does in Javascript?

Comment: Also, ending semi-colons in php are **NOT** optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

$randomstring .= substr($chars, $rnum, $rnum + 1);

Read the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1310683 bytes) on line 8

Comment: Actually it works as well as $chars[$rnum]. String behave like character arrays in PHP.